# How to use the 'ranked-model' gem with MTI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, multiple-tables

I want to use the 'ranked-model' gem with Multiple Table Inheritance.

My use case looks like this:

```
    class MitarbeiterListeEintrag < ActiveRecord::Base
    end
    
    class Mitarbeiter < MitarbeiterListeEintrag
      set_table_name "mitarbeiter"
    end
    
    class MitarbeiterTrenner < MitarbeiterListeEintrag
      set_table_name "mitarbeiter_trenner"
    end
    
    class CreateMitarbeiter < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :mitarbeiter do |t|
          t.references :team, null: false
          t.string :vorname, null: false
          t.string :nachname, null: false
          t.string :geburtsdatum, null: false
          t.integer :sort_order, null: false
        end
      end
    end
    
    class CreateMitarbeiterTrenner < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :mitarbeiter_trenner do |t|
          t.references :team, null: false
          t.string :name, null: false
          t.integer :sort_order, null: false
        end
      end  
    end
```

Mitarbeiter and MitarbeiterTrenner are two different tables but they share the sort order as they are displayed in the same list.

Answer (score 0):

To use the 'ranked-model' gem I need to add the following to the MitarbeiterListeEintrag model:

```
class MitarbeiterListeEintrag < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RankedModel
  ranks :sort_order
end
```